# C# Extracting a rsa public key from .cer (2048-bit) certificate and encrypting data using RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding method

Tags: c#, encryption, certificate, rsa, public-key

`I have imported the .cer certificate through IIS manager->Server Certificates-> import I want to extract the public key from a .cer certificate [(link)](http://developer.uidai.gov.in/site/sites/default/files/uidai_auth_stage.cer) and encrypt a string using the public key(RSA 2048 bit) extracted from the certificate,the method used should be RSA with ECB and PKCS1Padding

edit:added the below code

```
public static void SettingRSAParameters(){

 X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("D:\\cer.cer");
byte[] publicKey = cert.GetPublicKey();
int keyLength = publicKey.Length;
byte[] ExponentData = new byte[3];
byte[] ModulusData = new byte[256];

Array.Copy(publicKey, publicKey.Length - ExponentData.Length, ExponentData, 0, ExponentData.Length);
Array.Copy(publicKey, publicKey.Length - ExponentData.Length - 2 - ModulusData.Length, ModulusData, 0, ModulusData.Length);
ExponentData1 = ExponentData;
ModulusData1 = ModulusData;}
```

Extracting the modulus and exponent data in this fashion and plugging it in through the below code

```
static public byte[] Encryption(byte[] Data, RSAParameters RSAKey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
{
    SettingRSAParameters();
    RSAKey.Modulus = ModulusData1;
    RSAKey.Exponent = ExponentData1;

    try
    {
        byte[] encryptedData;
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
        {

            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKey);
            encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(Data, DoOAEPPadding);
            return encryptedData;
        }
    }
    catch (CryptographicException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code doesn't encrypt properly please check if the code is correct and also suggest as where to add the ciphermode ECB

Comment: *"code doesn't encrypt properly"* what do you mean by that? Are there errors? Is the result different from what you expect? If so, how? Please show example inputs and outputs.

Comment: Normally, you would encrypt your payload using an ephemeral symmetric key and then just use the asymmetric (RSA) key to exchange the symmetric key. This is certainly how the example code for RSACryptoServiceProvider works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f17a0e2k(v=vs.110).aspx I'd expect the symmetric algorithm to be some flavour of AES but you don't specify.

As a sidenote, ECB is not a good choice of ciphermode.

Comment: @Artjom B. I should actually send the encrypting data to a web service and they decrypt using their private key.When I post them the encrypted data(there are no errors) they are sending me an error code that data is not encrypted properly

Comment: @geoff_h the data which I am talking about is the symmetric key and web service specified that it has to be in ECB
also Iink which you have provided does'nt talk about RSA with ECB(PKCS1Padding issue is resolved)